Linux: encrypting a second disk without having to type the password on reboot
It is a long story but to make it short, we want to encrypt a newly attached disk but do not want to type the disk password on every boot -- inputting the disk password at the very first reboot is okay. The existing disk that contains the root file system is already encrypted but does not require us to type the password on boot. We are using Ubuntu 22.04 and grub-2.06.
Here are some backgrounds. My small team is assigned our only Linux server. We must add a second disk (actually, two disks but I guess how it works would be the same). The second disk is much larger. The disk is actually physically attached to the machine, already. Per employer's policy, all the disks must be encrypted. The IT team somehow provided two methods I will share below: one is how the first disk was encrypted and the other is the bash script we can use to encrypt the disk, which is not working.
The IT team, however, said that if I encrypt the disks now, we will have to type the password on boot and that we should re-install the root file system from scratch while configuring the second disk together. Is that, however, true?
As to how the first disk is configured, the IT team normally installed Ubuntu but chose something like the picture:
Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation + Encrypt the new Ubuntu Installation for Security
There seems to be an option that does "LVM" + "Encryption."
As to what the IT team suggested regarding the new disk encryption, it was a bash script, which did not work as is. There seem, however, to be hundreds lines of bash code but I think these are the relevant part as to how they normally encrypt the disk:
# created a partition table on the new disk, say, sda
sudo parted /dev/sda -s mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
echo ${some_manufactured_password} | sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 sda1_crypt
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt

Besides the bash script, there are follow-up instructions that tells us to add the partition to /etc/fstab and /etc/crtypttab.
Unfortunately, I would like to avoid doing the following: skipping adding the partition to the two files and rebooting the machine. The machine is geographically very far and doing that would require us to make a complicated arrangement.
If I skip that "adding the new partitions to the two files" part, would the bootloader still be asking the disk password?
If I want to encrypt the new disk but avoid the need of typing disk passwords on every boot, what should I do?

You can place the encryption keyfile in fstab options. Encryption keyfile should be secured against access from non root users.
